# Echo block of HTML that contains PHP functions

Tags: php, echo

I have a simple if-else statement--if true, I'd like it to echo this content:

```
<div id="login">
  <h2>Login</h2>
  <div class="box">
    <form method="POST" action="index.php/login">
      Username/Email:<br />
      <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo set_value("username"); ?>" size="50" class="form" />
      <?php echo form_error("username"); ?>
      Password:<br />
      <input type="password" name="password" value="<?php echo set_value("password"); ?>" size="50" class="form" />
      <?php echo form_error("password"); ?>
      <input type="submit" value="Login" name="login" />
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

and if false do something similar.

How should I approach this?  I'm a PHP noob (and I've been annoying the community here!)--so I'm standing at the echo function right now--I think I can set variables, but that's about it.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Same thing as you have been doing:

```
<?php
if some_condition
{
?>
    <p> I am inside the true condition due : <?php echo "true on condition" ?> </p>
<?
}
else
{
?>
    <p> I am inside the false condition due : <?php echo "false on condition" ?> </p>
<?
}
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can simply break out of PHP in the if/else statement.

```
if(true)
{
    ?>
    Regular HTML Here
    <?php
}
else
{
    ?>
    Regular HTML Here
    <?php
}
```

You can break out of PHP at any time using the '?>' operator, and with any control structure, it should show the code just as if you echo'd it. Another option would be to use output buffering.

```
if(true)
    {
        ob_start();

        ?>
        Regular Code Here
        <?php

        $contents = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
    }
```

This will leave the contents of what outputted between the start and end in $contents.

Finally, you could use an include() to only include your login form when you actually need it. (I prefer this method because I can put login forms almost anywhere on the site very easily)

```
if(true)
{
    include('loginform.php');
}
```

Comment: eh, my server doesn't allow "include".

Comment: Thats really weird lol. You could always call a function you put somewhere near the bottom of the code that outputs the login form. (You can break out of PHP in a function aswell, just like the first example)

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php if ($condition) { ?>

    <div id="login">
      <h2>Login</h2>
      <div class="box">
        <form method="POST" action="index.php/login">
          Username/Email:<br />
          <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo set_value("username"); ?>" size="50" class="form" />
          <?php echo form_error("username"); ?>
          Password:<br />
          <input type="password" name="password" value="<?php echo set_value("password"); ?>" size="50" class="form" />
          <?php echo form_error("password"); ?>
          <input type="submit" value="Login" name="login" />
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>

<?php } else { ?>

    other html here

<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just a suggestion; for readability and ease of flexibility, it is better to place what you want to display inside a variable first.

```
$html = "<form method='post' action='?'> ...... ";

if ($condition)
   $html .= "Error"
else
   $html .= "No problem"
....

<html>
  <body>
    <?php
      echo $html;
    ?>
   </body>
</html>
```

Or you can use a template. One which I would recommend is [EasyTemplate](http://phpclasses.sgboards.com/browse/package/3776.html).

Answer (score 1):

there's a form of php conditional that's somewhat easier to read for this, uses colon notation so instead of

```
<?php if ($condition) { ?>
...html
<?php } else { ?>
...html
<?php } endif; ?>
```

you do

```
<?php if ($condition) : ?>
...html
<?php else : ?>
...html
<?php endif; ?>
```

also if your config allows it, you can shorthand

```
<?= $variable ?>
```

instead of

```
<?php echo($variable); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Dropping out of php is the easiest way to do this. I find that using the [alternate control structures](http://us.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) makes this sort of code much more readable than stranded curly braces, especially if you have a lot of html.

```
<?php if (!$logged_in): ?>

    <div id="login">
      <h2>Login</h2>
      <div class="box">
        <form method="POST" action="index.php/login">
          Username/Email:<br />
          <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo set_value("username"); ?>" size="50" class="form" />
          <?php echo form_error("username"); ?>
          Password:<br />
          <input type="password" name="password" value="<?php echo set_value("password"); ?>" size="50" class="form" />
          <?php echo form_error("password"); ?>
          <input type="submit" value="Login" name="login" />
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>

<?php else: ?>

    // display html for a logged-in user

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this

echo htmlentities($string);

[htmlentities](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)

Set the string to the html code you want to output.

Comment: sorry, my bad. I thought you wanted the output to be the code.